# Getting List Of Installed Products c#

Tags: c#, .net, installation, registry, windows-installer

To Install/Uninstall/Update our software, our custom installer uses `WindowsInstaller.Installer.Products` to get the list of installed products from windows registry.

And on some client machines, an unknown software is probably adding a new entry to the registry '**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products**' a key with name something like 'ABCD'. This is causing `WindowsInstaller.Installer.Products` to throw an exception. I can re create this scenario by manually adding a registry key entry into '**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products**' named 'test'. And if I rename test to a new GUID then the simulated problem gets solved.

Can you suggest any possible workaround/solution?

Using MSIINV.exe tool would be difficult, as that is a 3rd party tool, but that seems to help.

Comment: Check out the MSI interop libraries in WiX DTF (below).  This is much easier and cleaner then trying to use COM Interop with WindowsInstaller.Installer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller namespace found in Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  It has:

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductInstallation> GetProducts(
    string productCode,
    string userSid,
    UserContexts context
)
```

> productCode (String)
>
> ProductCode (GUID) of the product instances to be
>   enumerated. Only instances of products within the scope of the context
>   specified by the userSid and context parameters will be enumerated.
>   This parameter may be set to null to enumerate all products in the
>   specified context.
>
> userSid (String)
>
> Specifies a security identifier
>   (SID) that restricts the context of enumeration. A SID value other
>   than s-1-1-0 is considered a user SID and restricts enumeration to the
>   current user or any user in the system. The special SID string s-1-1-0
>   (Everyone) specifies enumeration across all users in the system. This
>   parameter can be set to null to restrict the enumeration scope to the
>   current user. When context is set to the machine context only, userSid
>   must be null.
>
> context (UserContexts)
>
> Specifies the user context.

that wraps the Win32 MSI API MsiEnumProductsEx function.  This brings back a collection of ProductInstallation that you can do Linq queries against to find out anything you need to know about installed MSI's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see that WIX DTF is an open source project now, though was started by Microsoft. Isn't there much I can do with the Microsoft provided assemblies? I'm not a open-source hater, but it is difficult to put such a thing in here!

Comment: As an alternative, I am trying to use the ProductEx property like below... `Interop.WindowsInstaller.Installer.ProductEx["","",7]`. But I'm unable to fathom how to use the returned RecordList. This works in spite of having a 'bad' registry value mentioned above. Can you tell me how to use te returned RecordList in a c# application.

Comment: Windows Installer came out of the Windows Platform and only has support for Win32 and COM. There is also support for WMI via the Win32_Product class but frankly the WMI support is horribly broken and the COM support has issues generating interops the last time I checked.  There is no support for MSI in the .NET Framework Base Class Libraries.

Comment: If you don't want to take a dependency on this interop assembly and the API function you need to call is MsiEnumProductsEx, you can P/Invoke it directly without the help of this very nice libray.  Checkout the following for examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5773/Wrapping-the-Windows-Installer-2-0-API

Comment: Hi, Thank you again and sorry to bother you again,.. Anything about `Interop.WindowsInstaller.Installer.ProductEx` would help me a lot. I am supposed to get e RecordList from it, which probably I am. But I do not know how to take out Product Code from it.

Maybe casting {System.__ComObject} object which ProductEx returns to an appropriate class would do the trick...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to give you help using an approach that I know isn't optimal.  If I wouldn't do it myself, I wouldn't teach someone else to do it.

Comment: To save some work for others, this is a static method off of `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.ProductInstallation`