# how do I find which user has installed a MSI

Tags: windows-installer

During installation, user has selected 'Current User' option instead of 'All Users' in Installation UI. I want to remove that installation forcefully by another user and install upgraded MSI with 'All Users' option. I found that, removing certain registry keys will achieve my objective.

Now, I want to find which user has installed that specific MSI so that I can identify the right registry path. Is there any option available?

Regards,
Madhan

Comment: **Multiple** users may have installed the application and chosen the "Current User" option.

Comment: I agree on scenario about multiple users installing same MSI. I want to find all users who have instaleld the MSI. For a specific scenario, we want to support 'ALL Users' only and wanted to remove individual user installation during migration.

Comment: The information you are looking for only exists within each user(s) profile. (HKCU registry ).  You could try walking through HKEY_USERS\xxxx\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer  but in certain roaming profile scenarios the data won't be there for you to see.  Sometimes situations like this requires a utility to be run on logon since that's the only time available to ensure the data is in scope.

Comment: I thought about walking through registry key. I am exploring for alternate mechanism. But if no other option is availble, I need to fall back on approach suggested by Christopher Painter.

Comment: Is searching HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData better than HKEY_USERS from performance perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know an easy way to do this (e.g. query some regkey) but there is a function in the windows installer API called [MsiEnumProductsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It requires you to specify a User SID, if you use the SID "s-1-1-0" it querys all installed products for all users.

Im not sure how this behaves with roaming profiles though.

If this doesn't work for you the suggested solutions in the comments (walk through all users or trigger something on logon) are IMHO the right way

Comment: I used below post to get managed API for above API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274073/getting-list-of-installed-products-c-sharp